# HighCharts: How to pass x and y value of selected point to Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I am new to HighCharts, javascript, and rails. I have a highchart in my rails application. I need to pass the values of the x and y to rails of the point a users clicks on the chart series. I know about the selection event handler but not how to pass data from highcharts to the rails controller. Can someone point me to an example I can look through.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too late, probably you already have solved this. The selection event handler allows you to fire an event. You can fire an ajax request to a controller method with the values of the point which are accessed using 'this'. Many demos in highcharts show you how to access the values of points using this.